# git pull error: RPC failed; result=52, HTTP code = 0

Tags: git, bitbucket

I encounter this error message when try to perform git pull on my server

```
[user1@test projectfolder]$ git pull -v
Password for 'https://usergit@bitbucket.org': 
POST git-upload-pack (949 bytes)
POST git-upload-pack (999 bytes)
error: RPC failed; result=52, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

so far i have tried

```
git config http.postBuffer 1048576000
```

current config file

```
[core]

        compression = 0      
                     
[http]
        pullbuffer = 50k
        postBuffer = 1048576000
```

I have tried to increase the postBuffer to 1048576000.but still encounter error. size of the file is almost 1MB only. Can someone please suggest what else shoud i do?

Comment: Why is compression off?

Comment: The setting is there since i take over the project. how should i set the compression? @JimRedmond